# How do i use a MaskFormatter on a JFormattedTextField without knowing the length of the string?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

So I have a `JFormattedTextField` and I need to restrict the user from entering anything but letters and hyphens.  I'm not quite sure how to use the `MaskFormatter` without explicitly knowing the length of the string that is to be entered.

My code currently looks like this:

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter();
formatter.setValidCharacters("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabscedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-");
JFormattedTextField firstNameTextField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

When I call `firstNameTextField.setText(getName())`, the text does not get set, leaving me with an unusable, empty text field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want no commitment in terms of string length, i have the impression, that it is a lot easier to achieve the effect of a JFormattedTextField and its MaskFormatter, if you use a regular JTextField and a KeyListener with its KeyAdapter. You can check each keystroke against the allowed character string and either accept the character or beep.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i had a similar problem and what i used instead of jFormatter was jTextfield and acheived the same with keyListener

Heres the code

```
jTextFieldName.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
                char c = evt.getKeyChar();
                if(!Character.isDigit(c) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))
                {
                    f.getToolkit().beep();
                    evt.consume();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
```

Here 'f' is nothing but JFrame